# Unzip file with colon in the name on Windows

Tags: windows, zip

My university has a system to download any professor's lecture notes in bulk as zip files. After a recent update on the server-side, the zipped files (contents) have names like this:

```
WINSEM2022-23_BEEE201L_TH_VL2022123456789_2023-02-21_ReferenceMaterialI_TueFeb2100:00:00IST2023_Lecture3.pdf
```

When attempting to unzip, Windows gives this error (class ID redacted):
[image: Screenshot of error with error code 0x80070057]

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165960/error-0x80070057-the-parameter-is-incorrect-when-unzipping-files and [Mircosoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions), the colon in the filename could be a likely cause.

How do I unzip these files? 7-Zip also fails.

Comment: I'd notify the uni about the problem, and include the MS documentation you've reviewed. As a workaround, can you maybe unzip it from the command line, enclosing the file name in double quotes?

Comment: CLI is working, thanks. I have indeed notified the uni but they're notoriously slow to reply...

Comment: Ah good, nice to be able to help :-) From the uni that's sort of a ... well, stupid. Maybe talk to your professor "Hey after the server update we're not able to open your lecture files anymore, here's why" :-)

Comment: Send them to https://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/websites/writing/characters-avoid/ Colons are bad on Win, unix and Mac, though for different reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Tetsujin, I'll let them know whenever they reply to my initial email. I had already directed them to MS docs though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions